# How to remove leading zeros from 'negative' alphanumeric string

Tags: java, regex, guava, apache-commons

Good day everyone.

I have an alphanumeric value. For example: "-00000050.43". And I need to convert it to BigDecimal (prefer, 'cuz it's an amount of $) or Float or Double (depends on the count of digits after '.'. Usually there are two digits) like "-50.43".
So, I have 3 different solutions for **positive** alphanumeric value. Please see them below:

Regex

```
"00000050.43".replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

Apache Commons

```
StringUtils.stripStart("00000050.43","0");
```

And Google Guava

```
CharMatcher.is('0').trimLeadingFrom("00000050.43")
```

It doesn't work for a negative value. Unfortunately, I don't get any idea how to deal with '-' at the start.
Thanks, guys! Have a good day.

Comment: why not just parse it to a numeric type?

Comment: @Stultuske sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: You don't need to remove leading zeros to parse it to Bigdecimal. Just take the string as is : `BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("-00000050.43");`

Comment: @Eritrean yeap, and you are right. As a solution it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
"00000050.43".replaceFirst("^(-?)0+(?!$)", "$1")
```

The `^(-?)0+(?!$)` pattern will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(-?)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern will refer to this group value, if there is a `-` matched, it will be restored in the resulting string): an optional `-`
- `0+` - one or more zeros
- `(?!$)` - no end of string position immediately on the right allowed.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X6WwPO/2).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to transform the alphanumeric string value to `BigDecimal`, you don't need to make any action on this string.
`BigDecimal` has a constructor which takes a `string` alphanumeric value as an argument.

```java
String val = "-0000054.1";
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(val);
```

Comment: Sure, it works for my case as well as a regex. Thank you!

Comment: @junior_java_develop why do you want to use a regex, if it works without?

Comment: @AndyTurner in the case when a customer wants to add a requirement to the value. Like, store it in DB as varchar. So I don't need anymore hold this variable as a BigDecimal.

Comment: @junior_java_develop you could use `bd.toString()` should the need arise. Storing it in a String "just in case" is known as [stringly-typed code](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped).